# C++ 2 dim array new got 0?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have newed a 2 dim array, but the size of array got 0:

```
auto **p = new string*[7];
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
        p[i] = new string[4];
    }
cout << sizeof(p) / sizeof(string)<< endl;
```

Anyone could give me a specialized answer about this question:

1. Why the result output is 0, but the result of sizeof(p) is 8, if the Denominator and molecular is not zero how could be the result be 0? (if denominator is 0 then is not math.)
2. How to achieve that new a 2 dim array contains string correctly?

Comment: `sizeof(p)` is the size of a pointer, probably 8. `sizeof(string)` is the size of the class, probably more than 8. So `8 / more than 8` is 0, because it is an integer division.

Comment: The size of a pointer is *the size of the pointer itself*. You can not get the "size" of the data it points to. The `sizeof` "trick" you use only works with actual arrays. I suggest you use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead if you want a dynamic array. And if the sizes of the dimensions are fixed at compile-time, then you could use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead.

Comment: `sizeof(p)` yields the size of the pointer. So integer division with `sizeof(string)`is likely to result in `0`. Use an appropriate standard container to do that, e.g.: `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>`.

Comment: `std::vector<std::array<std::string,4>> tbl(7);`

Comment: use a vector of vectors, if you're using new in modern c++, you're doing it wrong ;)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Why is then the `sizeof (string**) == sizeof(p)`?

Comment: @Ron Because `p` is of the type `string**`? And generally speaking, on all platforms I know of the size of a pointer is the same, no matter what it points to.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Right, the wording got me confused. So you can get the size of the type of the pointer but not the size of the actual data.

Comment: @Ron That's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you allocate memory using [`new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) for arrays, it attempts to allocate storage and on success returns a pointer to the initial element of the array. Because here the allocated array decayed to a pointer, you lost the information about the array size in bytes, so you cannot calculate the number of elements as:

```
auto numberOfElements = sizeof(array) / sizeof(element);
```

In your example the `sizeof(p)` returns the same as `sizeof(std::string**)` which is based on your architecture. The `sizeof(string)` may be bigger, than `sizeof(std::string**)`, therefore from integer division you got `0`.

In [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) is it strongly recommended to use the [Standard containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) instead manual allocation and deallocation. As comments under your question mention, [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is what you should use in your example, as follows:

```
vector<vector<string>> p(7, vector<string>(4));
cout << p.size() << endl;
```

**Note:** when you allocated memory for `string*[7]`, you've clearly specified the number of elements, which is `7`.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(p)` is the size of the pointer, which in your system, might be 8.

`sizeof(string)` is the size of the class, which is something greater than 8.

As a result you print:

```
8 / greaterThan8
```

which gives you 0, since it's an integer division. If you cast it to float, it won't print 0.

Answer (score 0):

sizeof(string) is greater than sizeof(p)

For such integer division the result will be 0.

For example 1/4 is not 0.25, it's 0.